# Strange buildbot python behavior

Tags: python, buildbot

EDIT for some explanations: The buildbot is a continous integration system in python which can be controlled by a web interface. In this web interface you have a "Waterfall" page where you can choose a specific builder and trigger a build with a "Force build" button.

URL: http://trac.buildbot.net/

The background: We have a cluster of builders which are continous (check every few minutes if a change happened and if yes, rebuild) or nightly (build every night). Our system so far has only *one* specific enterprise builder for *every* project. This was done by enforcing that every project must be found under a constant URL like

```
https://myrepositioryurl/{$projectname}.
```

Then when a project needs an enterprise build you need to choose one project XYZ and the buildbot assumes that the project needs to be checked out under

```
https://myrepositioryurl/{$projectname}.
```

This is very rigid and I wanted to reconfigure the buildbot that projects can be under different URLs. During the setup of the builders which is started by "buildbot start master" a config file of our projects is read and stored in a ConfigParser object. In the following source code it is the clzoptions var und my URL I want to use should be

```
https://mytesturl/XYZ.
```

for project XYZ.
I added now my different URLs under a "svnBaseURL" entry for a test project. Now I have encountered something which I do not quite understand in my python class which creates the builders. First the source:

```
import os
import logging

from xcodebuild import xcodebuild
from projects import Projects

from buildbot.config import BuilderConfig
from buildbot.process.factory import BuildFactory
from buildbot.steps.source import SVN
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand, WithProperties
from buildbot.process.properties import Property


class builders(object):
    clzoptions = Projects().options


    def __init__(self):
        aProject = Projects()
        self.options = aProject.options


    def enterprise_checkout_url(self, curProjectName):
        return curProjectName

    def create_enterprise_builder(self):
        factory = BuildFactory()
        factory.addStep(ShellCommand(name='svn checkout',
                                     haltOnFailure=True,
                                     description='svn checkout',
                                     descriptionDone='svn checkout done',
                                     command=['svn', 'checkout', '--username', 'admin', self.enterprise_checkout_url(WithProperties('%(project)s')), '.']))



        builderConfig = BuilderConfig(name="foobuilder",
                                      category="OnDemand",
                                      slavenames=[ "buildslave01" ],
                                      factory=factory)
        return builderConfig



    def get_all_builders(self):
        builders = []

        builders.append(self.create_enterprise_builder())

        return builders
```

I have melted it down to the core problem, there are many more builders inside. The key function is self.enterprise_checkout_url(WithProperties('%(project)s')).

If I call that builder with the project name "XYZ" in the Waterfall, I get as result

```
svn checkout --username admin XYZ .
```

for the ShellCommand. While this is nonsensical because it is not an URL, I see that the
parameter curProjectName evaluates to "XYZ".
Easy so far,right ? Lets change now that function...

```
def enterprise_checkout_url(self, curProjectName):
  return builders.clzoptions.get("XYZ", "svnBaseURL"))
```

and get

```
svn checkout --username admin https://mytesturl/XYZ .
```

This is nearly the thing I need,

```
https://mytesturl/XYZ
```

is the right path. But the key is constant, I need it to be variable. But at least I know that the dictionary exists and has the correct entry for XYZ.

Now the problem I simply do not understand.

Lets try now

```
def enterprise_checkout_url(self, curProjectName):
      return builders.clzoptions.get(curProjectName, "svnBaseURL"))
```

and oops, he does not build

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: <buildbot.process.properties.WithProperties instance at 0x1073739e0>
```

Ok, during the compile phase curProjectName may not be set, how about:

```
def enterprise_checkout_url(self, curProjectName):
    projects = builders.clzoptions.sections()
    for project in projects:
      if project == curProjectName:
        return builders.clzoptions.get(project, "svnBaseURL" )
```

which compiles.
I am getting all my projects, test if the curProjectName is right and then return my svnBaseURL with the project key which should be equal to curProjectName.
But I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Your turn. I have tried to use str(), repr(), eval() on curProjectName, but to no avail. I cannot access both the existing dictionary and curProjectName.

Comment: Hello. With what kind of instruction do you "call the builder" as you say ?

Comment: All build commands are started by the Web UI in the Waterfall display. I type in the project name and then press "Force build".

Comment: In which part of the code are placed the lines ``projects = builders.clzoptions.sections()`` and following ?

Comment: What does trigger "Force build"?

Comment: I have reedited my question to answer as much as possible. "Force build" triggers the buildslave, a daemon thread controlled by the buildmaster to execute the build scripts.

Comment: Thank you. I've read your update but not all understood. I found various documentation on Buildbot. That's very interesting. I try to understand more, studying some pages on the web. The following is particularly interesting for me: (http://anybox.fr/blog/retour-dexperience-sur-buildbot-1-3) It gives general explanation that I need to understand more your problem.

Comment: Well, the error ``'NoneType' object is not iterable`` means that a try to iterate in **None** has been done. But **None** isn't iterable, uh ? The only place where I see an iteration in your code is ``for project in projects:``. So I beg **projects** is **None**. As you define ``projects = builders.clzoptions.sections()`` , the problem is probably that ``sections()``  returns **None**.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you ?

```
class builders(object):

    builders = []
    print 'id of buiders just created ==',id(builders)

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.the = x

    def enterprise_checkout_url(self, curProjectName):
        return curProjectName

    def create_enterprise_builder(self,yy):
        builderConfig = dict(descriptionDone='-SVN-',
                             command=yy)
        return builderConfig

    def get_all_builders(self):
        print 'id of builders inside get_all_builders ==',id(builders)
        print 'id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders ==',id(builders.builders)

        builders.builders.append(self.create_enterprise_builder((self.the)))

        return builders.builders

print 'id of class builders ==',id(builders)
print '\n################################\n'

b = builders('BOF')
print b.get_all_builders()

print '\n=================================\n'

b2 = builders('MOTO')
print b2.get_all_builders()
```

result

```
id of buiders just created == 18709040
id of class builders == 13819408

################################

id of builders inside get_all_builders == 13819408
id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders == 18709040
[{'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'BOF'}]

=================================

id of builders inside get_all_builders == 13819408
id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders == 18709040
[{'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'BOF'}, {'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'MOTO'}]
```

EDIT

Ther's a problem with my code.
If the instruction `print b2.get_all_builders()` is executed two times, the result is

```
id of buiders just created == 18709040
id of class builders == 13819408

################################

id of builders inside get_all_builders == 13819408
id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders == 18709040
[{'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'BOF'}]

=================================

id of builders inside get_all_builders == 13819408
id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders == 18709040
[{'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'BOF'}, {'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'MOTO'}]

id of builders inside get_all_builders == 13819408
id of builders.builders inside get_all_builders == 18709040
[{'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'BOF'}, {'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'MOTO'}, {'descriptionDone': '-SVN-', 'command': 'MOTO'}]
```

One of the dictionaries appears two times.

Since I don't understand very well your problem and I'm not sure of what you want exactly, I don't know how to correct it